# Is it safe to access public keys (in front-end modules) using the dotenv library, if server-side (private keys) are also stored in the same .env file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, node-modules, dotenv

Is is safe to access PUBLIC keys for client-side/front-end code using the 'dotenv' library when my `.env` file is also storing PRIVATE (i.e. secret) keys that are used only by the server?

Do I need to worry about exposing PRIVATE keys used by the server-side code while accessing PUBLIC keys on the front-end?

For example:

```
/* SOME FRONT-END (CLIENT-SIDE) COMPONENT */

require('dotenv').config() // really hope I'm not exposing my private keys here 

const myPublicKeyThatIsOkayForThePublicToSee = process.env.SOME_PUBLIC_KEY

// end of file... never access any PRIVATE keys, but hopefully they weren't exposed above
```

I am hoping to rest easy knowing that I could store all of my keys in a single file as this would make my development process a lot easier (project more maintainable, etc.). Seems annoying to have to store keys in two separate places; would rather just have a single large configuration text document (like the .env file) where all keys live and where I could just name PRIVATE keys with a "PRIVATE_" tag and "PUBLIC_" for PUBLIC variables.

Example desired `.env` file:

```
PUBLIC_SOME_3RD_PARTY_API_AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN=d678h678hs6s78g6h7s8gf9g6f9

PRIVATE_SOME_3RD_PARTY_APP_KEY=c41v987gtuig78ghjk43j6h50952gds
PRIVATE_SOME_3RD_PARTY_APP_PASSWORD=93kjc7830hg874njbx89724oidbf78
```

I apologize if this has been answered before, but I figured it was worth it to ask since there could be potential security issues if I implemented key storage/access incorrectly in my app.

If this isn't safe, what would be a better way of achieving front-end key storage? Should I just define a separate `public.client.keys.js` file or something to this effect and import the keys where necessary in front-end modules?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes, that's safe.  As long as the environment variable name is hard-coded in the server and can't be influenced by the client, it's safe to read it that way.

Comment: I should add that you need to worry about the physical security of the private keys (who else has physical access to the computer) and if any other programs running on the server have access to them and if they are secure.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, thank you. Yes, as I assume is typical, I am just reading/accessing the (manually entered) .env variables throughout my app (both server and client-side) and never writing to the file programmatically (i.e. during runtime). I realized that I never actually confirmed that this practice of accessing the variables in this manner was safe though, and although I thought it was fine, I figured it was well worth it to make sure. And yes, I do understand the importance of physically storing keys securely in both prod/dev and .gitignoring the .env file, etc. Really appreciate the help.